# App Bindings on com.apple.spaces.plist, How manipulate?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, spaces

In com.apple.spaces exist the property app-bindings
[image]
I am actually using Core Graphics to get and set values of Space Properties: [CGSSpace](https://github.com/NUIKit/CGSInternal/blob/master/CGSSpace.h)

But there doesn't exist a function related to App Bindings, how can I get and set these values? exists some private API related?